# Implementing reactive pattern in existing code

Tags: rx-java, observable, reactive-programming, system.reactive

I am trying to implement reactive patterns in my existing application.

So I start with DAO layer. Like any other DAO layer, current implementation fetches list of entities from database by making use of JPA.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT e from MyEntity e WHERE....")
List<MyEntity> getMyEntities();
```

Now, I can make Observable from List.

But Observable is a data stream which is asynchronous and pushes data/events on fly. But in this case,List is already complete.

So what benefits do I get from reactive pattern in such use cases?

Comment: I would say none. What are you trying to accomplish by implementing reactive programming? If you can adequately answer that that you can assess per situation whether it is a good fit or not.

Comment: This is really going to depend on your application, which you haven't shown us anything much of. If you have any sort of need for polling in your app, or if a user clicks a refresh button, etc, then you can turn your DAO into a reactive source. But without further information it's hard to advise.

Comment: My application basically fetches images from database and make them available to user, displayed in a browser.User can then draw geometry figures like polygons, polylines etc on image with mouse and keyboard actions, and finally save the image. Save persists these added geometries too.When same image ie reread, those drawn geometries too are displayed. My main objective to implement reactive patterns are of-course to improve application responsiveness and resilience,and also to implement back pressure.

Comment: @Mandroid - And none of that description told us anything about how your application should be reactive. What events/timers do you need to respond to? And how do those relate to your `List<MyEntity>`?

Comment: What I am basically looking for is that when my application is under stress and finds it difficult to serve all requests in timely manner, then user must get to know it  with proper message. MyEntity contains the data which I send back to user as JSON response. Forgive me if I am not being clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking at this the wrong way. You are essentially asking something like this: "So I pull some data from a database and return it is a collection. If I change the datatype of this collection from enumerable to observable, how does that benefit anything?" Obviously it doesn't offer any benefit.

In your model, you have a program defined 'imperatively.' The program is specifically asking for information about changes, commanding your object model to add these changes into its polygon structures, commanding a database to store them when necessary, commanding a screen to render them when loaded, etc.

In contrast, a reactive model is a declarative expression of things in reaction to changes. You do this by *declaring* a polygon as being a function of mouse move events in combination with mouse button events. The polygon is declared as function of those things. Pictures are functions of polygons. Database storage events are declared as functions of pictures in combination with UI save events, just as polygons are functions of different mouse event streams. Pictures are also functions of load events. Screen updates are functions of pictures, etc...

You have to completely change the way you think of 'programs'. In the reactive model a load picture event will result in a stream of events of loaded polygons and screen updates, all of which could be happening concurrently with your mouse draw events. All of that happens as a result of how the things in your domain model are declared. Pictures appearing on screen fall out naturally from the declaration of how load events and screen update events are *declared* . The responsiveness there would be that if a huge, detailed picture with millions of polygons were being loaded, you could paginate or stream your load and let the load continue while the user is able to interact with it in parallel.